# Need help understanding the equation

Tags: z3, z3py

Have the equation Pell `x*x - 193 * y*y = 1`

in z3py:

```
x = BitVec('x',64)
y = BitVec('y',64)
solve(x*x - 193 * y*y == 1, x > 0, y > 0)
```

Result: `[y = 2744248620923429728, x = 8169167793018974721]`

Why?

P.S. Valid answer: [y = 448036604040, x = 6224323426849]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to use Bit-vector arithmetic to solve Diophantine equations. The basic idea is to use `ZeroExt` to avoid the overflows pointed out by Pad. For example, if we are multiplying two bit-vectors `x` and `y` of size `n`, then we must add `n` zero bits to `x` and `y` to make sure that the result will not overflow. That is, we write:

```
 ZeroExt(n, x) * ZeroExt(n, y)
```

The following set of Python functions can be used to "safely" encode any Diophantine equation `D(x_1, ..., x_n) = 0` into Bit-vector arithmetic. By "safely", I mean if there is a solution that fits in the number of bits used to encode `x_1`, ..., `x_n`, then it will eventually be found modulo resources such as memory and time.
Using these function, we can encode the Pell's equation `x^2 - d*y^2 == 1` as `eq(mul(x, x), add(val(1), mul(val(d), mul(y, y))))`. The function `pell(d,n)` tries to find values for `x` and `y` using `n` bits.

The following link contains the complete example:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/Pehp

That being said, it is super expensive to solve Pell's equation using Bit-vector arithmetic. The problem is that multiplication is really hard for the bit-vector solver. The complexity of the encoding used by Z3 is quadratic on `n`. On my machine, I only managed to solve Pell's equations that have small solutions. Examples: `d = 982`, `d = 980`, `d = 1000`, `d = 1001`. In all cases, I used a `n` smaller than `24`. I think there is no hope for equations with very big minimal positive solutions such as `d = 991` where we need approximately 100 bits to encode the values of `x` and `y`.
For these cases, I think a specialized solver will perform much better.

BTW, the rise4fun website has a small timeout, since it is a shared resource used to run all research prototypes in the Rise group. So, to solve non trivial Pell's equations, we need to run Z3 on our own machines.

```
def mul(x, y):
  sz1 = x.sort().size()
  sz2 = y.sort().size()
  return ZeroExt(sz2, x) * ZeroExt(sz1, y)
def add(x, y):
  sz1 = x.sort().size()
  sz2 = y.sort().size()
  rsz = max(sz1, sz2) + 1
  return ZeroExt(rsz - sz1, x) + ZeroExt(rsz - sz2, y)  
def eq(x, y):
  sz1 = x.sort().size()
  sz2 = y.sort().size()
  rsz = max(sz1, sz2)
  return ZeroExt(rsz - sz1, x) == ZeroExt(rsz - sz2, y)
def num_bits(n):
  assert(n >= 0)
  r = 0
  while n > 0:
    r = r + 1
    n = n / 2
  if r == 0:
    return 1
  return r
def val(x):
  return BitVecVal(x, num_bits(x))
def pell(d, n):
  x  = BitVec('x', n)
  y  = BitVec('y', n)
  solve(eq(mul(x,x), add(val(1), mul(val(d), mul(y, y)))) , x > 0, y > 0)
```